# HTML5 "Canvas is null"

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Can anyone help me? I'm putting together an infographic within a sliding carousel and I'm getting the error "canvas is null". I think I may have a few bits of code in the wrong place, but I'm having trouble working out which bits. I think it's causing the SVG that's supposed to appear in the background of each sliding `<li>` to not be displayed.

Can anyone work out what's causing these problems? The page is here: http://weaver-wp.weavertest.com/radiation-infographic/

Thanks,
David

Comment: Are you trying this in a browser without canvas support? I think IE8 is such a candidate.

Comment: Testing in Chrome, Safari and Firefox, so it should be OK. Should have the support, but not sure if I'm missing the right MIME declarations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looping from 1 to 32, but there are only 31 canvas elements on the page. In the 32nd iteration, `document.getElementById('myCanvas_32')` is returning `null`, hence the error.

Comment: Very swift! Thanks for spotting that one Box9. Although my main question has been answered, my images are still not loading. Any ideas?

Comment: @Dalogi, not sure which background SVG you're talking about?

Comment: The 'canvas' CSS is set to background: url('images/radiation-images/radiation-silhouette.svg'), but this is not displaying on the site properly. Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: @Dalogi The mime type for the image is set to `text/xml`. It should be `image/svg+xml` instead.

Comment: @Dalogi, this is done on the server, typically through configuration files. Here is a process for configuring Apache correctly: http://kaioa.com/node/45.

Comment: @Box9 Ahh, I see. Thanks for pointing this out :) Much respect!